# jcabi Aether basic example doesn't work

Tags: java, maven, jcabi

On jcabi Aether's [main web page](http://aether.jcabi.com/) is a simple example for use outside of Maven, which boasts it needs but a single Maven dependency (jcabi-aether 0.9).  I've created a project for that "Main", just to try it, but it seems to have some, um, difficulties.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File local = new File("/tmp/local-repository");
    Collection<RemoteRepository> remotes = Arrays.asList(
      new RemoteRepository(
        "maven-central",
        "default",
        "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
      )
    );
    Collection<Artifact> deps = new Aether(remotes, local).resolve( // #1
      new DefaultArtifact("junit", "junit-dep", "", "jar", "4.10"),
      "runtime"
    );
  }
}
```

For starters, #1 generates this error (from Eclipse):

*The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject. Fix the build path then try building this project*

So... no big deal, I guess: I'll just toss in maven-project (2.2.1).  Hey, it compiles!  Great!  But wait, when running it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/settings/building/SettingsBuildingException
    at org.test.aether.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

Hmmm.  Okay, so I'll also throw in maven-settings-builder (3.3.2).  Now we should be good to go... right?  Well, no: this time, I get voluminous exception output, like this:

```
java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting class com/jcabi/aether/Aether.
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_9dd1198.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:89)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:169)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:365)
```

Don't get me wrong.  Sounds like a great project.  But does it actually work?  And what's up with the example on the front page?  Anybody have any experience with it?

Comment: what is your java version ? compile & runtime

Comment: both compile time and runtime are same ?

Comment: Yes.  Using Eclipse to both build & launch.

Comment: @TimW this could be a problem with jacoco. I'm a creator of jcabi-aether, please create a ticket at https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-aether/issues This can easily be a bug in the library

Comment: Hi just wondering was any solution for this issue found??
I can't seem to find anything on the issues link.

Answer (score 1):

From the github code for jcabi-aether at https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-aether/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jcabi/aether/Aether.java , turns out we do need to add the following two dependencies:

- org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:1.13.1
- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.0.3

I added these and got the example code to run

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.sonatype.aether.artifact.Artifact;
import org.sonatype.aether.repository.RemoteRepository;
import org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException;
import org.sonatype.aether.util.artifact.DefaultArtifact;

import com.jcabi.aether.Aether;

public class RunAether {

public static void main(String[] args) throws DependencyResolutionException {

    File local = new File("/tmp/local-repository");
    Collection<RemoteRepository> remotes = Arrays.asList(
      new RemoteRepository(
        "maven-central",
        "default",
        "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
      )
    );
    Collection<Artifact> deps = new Aether(remotes, local).resolve(
      new DefaultArtifact("junit", "junit-dep", "", "jar", "4.10"),
      "runtime"
    );

    System.out.println("Got the Junit dependencies");
}

}
```

My pom file dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcabi-aether</artifactId>
        <version>0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.aether</groupId>
        <artifactId>aether-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```